# Parse date and Convert W. Europe Standard Time to UTC

Tags: c#, datetime

**TL:DR**: I have the following input string:

```
Thu Mar 09 2017 18:00:00 GMT+0100
```

And I am trying to convert it to a `DateTime` object using the format:

```
"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

This obviously doesn't work as I am ignoring the `GMT+0100` part. How can I include this?

---

I don't manage to parse and convert following input to a correct UTC DateTime object:

input string *selectedDate*:

```
1,Thu Mar 09 2017 18:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

function:

```
var splittedValues = selectedDate.Split(',');

var selectDayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)int.Parse(splittedValues[0]);

var selectedTime = DateTime.ParseExact(splittedValues[1].Substring(0, 24),
    "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

// The (... + 7) % 7 ensures we end up with a value in the range [0, 6]
int daysUntilNextTargetDay = ((int)selectDayOfWeek - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

DateTime nextTargetDay = today.AddDays(daysUntilNextTargetDay).AddHours(selectedTime.Hour).AddMinutes(selectedTime.Minute);

return nextTargetDay.ToUniversalTime();
```

results time portion is always `18:00:00` 
should be `17:00` as the input was actually GMT +01

Whats the issue here?

update:
as others pointed out there were mistakes so I updated my code to:

```
var splittedValues = selectedDate.Split(',');

var selectDayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)int.Parse(splittedValues[0]);

var selectedTime = DateTime.ParseExact(splittedValues[1].Substring(0, 33),
                "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();

// The (... + 7) % 7 ensures we end up with a value in the range [0, 6]
int daysUntilNextTargetDay = ((int)selectDayOfWeek - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

DateTime nextTargetDay = DateTime.Today.AddDays(daysUntilNextTargetDay).AddHours(selectedTime.Hour).AddMinutes(selectedTime.Minute);

return nextTargetDay;
```

but now the parsing fails as the substring does not match  `"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"`
how does the GMT+0100 has to be included here?

Comment: Why did you tag this as JavaScript?

Comment: First pick a language C# or JavaScript. Secondly I think the `d` should be `dd` but I may be wrong. Thirdly you are substringing to 24 characters length effectively returning `Thu Mar 09 2017 18:00:00` so the `DateTime` object has no way of knowing it should be plus 1.

Comment: By result is `18:00:00` do you mean `selectedTime` holds that value?

Comment: Side note: Why are you doing: `DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);` and not `DateTime.Today` or `DateTime.Now.Date`?

Comment: I tagged Javascript as the input string is coming from javascript. @TheLethalCoder thx for this hint. I totally overread this. I copied this line of code from a topic here. Moreover I know that the result is not only "18:00" but I wanted to simplify

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: I forgot to remove this line DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified); and stick to the simple way like you suggested. This was just to test something.

Comment: But extending the substring to index 33 will cause an exception during parsing. How do I have to include the GMT in parsing?

Comment: @el_buck0 I am not sure; I have linked to the DateTime format specifiers MSDN page in my answer, there may be one there that fits your needs.

Comment: I have edited a `TL:DR` into the question to give the short version of the problem without the fluff. If you feel the edit deviates to much from your intent feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TimeZoneInfo` when converting between specific time zones:

```
TimeZoneInfo westInfo =
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");

DateTime westTime = DateTime.Parse("2012.12.04T08:35:00");
DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(westTime, westInfo);
```

To address your confusion:

- DateTime.Parse as used here makes no assumptions about the timezone of the given value. IT stores it with a `DateTimeKind` of `Unspecified`.
- `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` as used here expects an `Unspecified` datetime, reads it as if it is in the explicitly specified time zone, and converts it to UTC.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer because I believe it gets to the core of the problem and hints at the way to fix it. However, I have implemented the code necessary for this question in my answer. Feel free to add it into your answer if you want!

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to this (adding `ToUniversalTime()` before adding days) fixed it for me.

```
 DateTime nextTargetDay = today.ToUniversalTime().AddDays(daysUntilNextTargetDay).AddHours(selectedTime.Hour).AddMinutes(selectedTime.Minute);
```

Then of course you can just `return nextTargetDay;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) I can spot an initial problem with your code. This is that you are using `d` where you should be using `dd` as the day is `09` not `9`.

> - `d`: The day of the month, from 1 through 31.
> - `dd`: The day of the month, from 01 through 31.

Secondly, the reason the `+1` is "ignored" is that you exclude it in the substring, i.e.

```
splittedValues[1].Substring(0, 24) == "Thu Mar 09 2017 18:00:00";
```

So essentially you need to include that part of the string with the correct format specifier (I'm not sure which one). Or interrogate it yourself and subtract one hour off of the result as needed.

---

Side note: The following code is weird (in my opinion, there may be a reason for it):

```
DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

You can either use [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DateTime.Now.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

As mentioned in the [answer by @calypso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42699560/4631427) you can use the [`TimeZoneInfo` class.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) Their answer goes over a general approach of how to use it. But for your particular example you can do (code is untested but looks like it should work):

```
var selectedTime = DateTime.ParseExact(splittedValues[1].Substring(0, 24), "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(splittedValues[1].Substring(splittedValues[1].IndexOf("(") + 1).TrimEnd(")"));
DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(selectedTime, timeZoneInfo);
```

Comment: thanks. just updated my code but now I am struggeling parsing

Comment: thanks ! but i think it should be Substring(splittedValues[1].IndexOf("(")+1).TrimEnd(')'));

Comment: @el_buck0 You can accept the answer that was most helpful to you and also upvote answers that are helpful. This is good as it helps future readers find solutions to their problems easier and faster.

Comment: okay fine. this works great for the timezone I posted initially but fails for UTC: {"The time zone ID 'Coordinated Universal Time' was not found on the local computer."}

Comment: @el_buck0 In short a timezone with that name is not on your system. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.